# Calculate minimum value based on constraints

Tags: arithmetic

This seems like a bit of a simple question in amongst all the 'proper' maths, but I'm a bit rusty...

If I have the following constraints:

$$ A = c(T - x) $$

$$ x - A > 0 $$

$$ 0 < c < 1 $$

I don't think that there is a way to calculate the minimum value that x can be to satisfy these contraints (for a fixed c and T) without using an iterative approach. Is that correct?

Comment: What about $A$, is it fixed?